# Am I right that the syntax of 'merge' and 'rebase' means opposite operation?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I'm not sure what branch gets affected after `merge` and `rebase`.

**Merge**

```
// I merge master INTO the dev. So dev is affected. A branch I'm now on
$ git checkout dev
$ git merge master
```

**Rebase**

```
// I do absolutely opposite
// I'm on dev
// I place dev changes ONTO master. master is affected, a branch I'm not on
$ git checkout dev
$ git rebase master
```

Comment: In both cases, only the current branch is modified.

Answer (score 4):

No, when rebasing you're moving `dev` to sit ontop of `master`. `master` remains unchanged.

In a situation like

```
A-B-C------D   # master
     \
      `-E-F    # dev
```

running

```
git checkout dev
git merge master
```

will result in

```
A-B-C------D      # master
     \      \
      `-E-F--M    # dev
```

and running

```
git checkout dev
git rebase master
```

will result in

```
A-B-C------D          # master
            \
             `-E-F    # dev
```

In both instances, only `dev` is modified.

Comment: Note that the above graph (after rebasing) should result in `A-B-C-D-E'-F'`

Clarification: `E'` and `F'` will introduce the same changes and have the same commit info (author, message, date) as `E` and `F`, but due to the fact that `E`'s parent will now be `D` instead of `C`, its commit hash will change. And consequently, by the same token, `F`'s commit hash will change as well. Even though to us humans commits `E` and `E'` _look_ the same, they are not. Be aware of this in case you are [rebasing a shared branch](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase).

Answer (score 0):

Rebase is not correct.

The dev branch is checkout from the master-two-days-ago. It is base on master-two-days-ago. When you `git rebase master`, equivalent to the dev branch is checkout from the master-now, dev is affected.